# Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloud9

Environment = AWS cloud, DynamoDB, AWS Cloud9, Python, JSON.

I am trying to right these items into a DynamoDB table with the command **aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://Sensors.json** in my Cloud9 CLI.

When I do run the command it returns this error **Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded**

The .json file is located in the same AWS Cloud9 directory and where I am running the command and where I am trying to create dynamodb tables. I believe this has to be some kind of formatting issue, but I just cannot see where.

**Here is full JSON code**

```
{
    "Sensors": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Bears.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Chicago Bears"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2020" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "001"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Chicago IL"}
                }
            }    
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Bengals.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Cincinnati Bengals"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2021" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "002"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Cincinnati OH"}
                }
            }    
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Bills.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Buffalo Bills"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2022" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "003"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Orchard Park NY"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Broncos.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Denver Broncos"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2023" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "004"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Denver CO"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Browns.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Cleveland Browns"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2024" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "005"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Cleveland OH"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Cardinals.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Arizona Cardinals"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2025" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "006"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Glendale AR"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Chiefs.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Kansas City Chiefs"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2026" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "007"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Kansas City MO"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Colts.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Indianapolis Colts"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2027" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "008"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Indianapolis IN"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Cowboys.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Dallas Cowboys"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2028" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "009"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Dallas TX"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Falcons.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Atlanta Falcons"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2029" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "010"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Atlanta GA"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Jaguars.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Jacksonville Jaguars"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2030" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "011"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Jacksonville FL"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Lions.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Detroit Lions"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2031" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "012"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Detroit MI"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Packers.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Greeb Bay Packers"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2032" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "013"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Green Bay WI"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Panthers.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Carolina Panthers"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2033" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "014"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Charlotte NC"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Raiders.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Las Vegas Raiders"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2034" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "015"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Las Vegas NV"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Rams.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Los Angeles Rams"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2035" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "016"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Los Angeles CA"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Ravens.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Baltimore Ravens"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2036" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "017"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Baltimore MD"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Saints.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "New Orleans Saints"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2037" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "018"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"New Orleans LA"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Texans.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Houston Texans"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2038" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "019"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Houston TX"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Vikings.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Minnesota Vikings"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2039" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "020"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Minnesota MN"}
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

**Full Error below**

```
Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received: {
    "Sensors": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Bears.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Chicago Bears"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2020" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "001"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Chicago IL"}
                }
            }    
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Bengals.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Cincinnati Bengals"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2021" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "002"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Cincinnati OH"}
                }
            }    
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Bills.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Buffalo Bills"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2022" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "003"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Orchard Park NY"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Broncos.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Denver Broncos"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2023" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "004"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Denver CO"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Browns.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Cleveland Browns"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2024" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "005"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Cleveland OH"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Cardinals.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Arizona Cardinals"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2025" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "006"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Glendale AR"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Chiefs.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Kansas City Chiefs"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2026" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "007"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Kansas City MO"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Colts.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Indianapolis Colts"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2027" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "008"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Indianapolis IN"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Cowboys.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Dallas Cowboys"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2028" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "009"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Dallas TX"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Falcons.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Atlanta Falcons"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2029" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "010"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Atlanta GA"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Jaguars.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Jacksonville Jaguars"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2030" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "011"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Jacksonville FL"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Lions.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Detroit Lions"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2031" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "012"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Detroit MI"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Packers.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Greeb Bay Packers"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2032" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "013"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Green Bay WI"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Panthers.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Carolina Panthers"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2033" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "014"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Charlotte NC"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Raiders.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Las Vegas Raiders"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2034" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "015"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Las Vegas NV"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Rams.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Los Angeles Rams"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2035" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "016"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Los Angeles CA"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Ravens.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Baltimore Ravens"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2036" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "017"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Baltimore MD"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Saints.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "New Orleans Saints"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2037" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "018"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"New Orleans LA"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Texans.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Houston Texans"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2038" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "019"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Houston TX"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Images/Vikings.png"},
                    "SenorDescription": {"S": "Minnesota Vikings"},
                    "SampleRate": {"N": "2039" },
                    "Sensor": {"S": "020"},
                    "Locations": {"S":"Minnesota MN"}
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON looks correct. I would suggest ensuring you're reaching the file correctly and it's saved in the correct format.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON is incorrect, there is a comma after the last item in the array, just before the closing square bracket.

> ```
>        },
>     ] 
> }
> ```

The same comma can bee seen in the aws cli command output, delete it from the source file and try again.